# Little issue script tinfoleak 1.5

Tags: python

I have a script from tinfoleak 1.5 and after some obstacles, I have filled up all the information (consumer key/secret and token/token secret) on the `tinfoleak.py` and `tinfoleak.conf` files, but when I execute the script

```
chmod +x tinfoleak.py
```

and then

```
python tinfoleak.py -h
```

It shows me the following error

> global name 'and here is my consumer key, so i can't write' is not defined

I don't understand where is the error and what to do

Comment: In order to do so we will need to see a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can reproduce the issue. Remember to take out any passwords/tokens.

Comment: Hello, i try to post the entire script but it's say the -Body limit is 30000- and I exceeded the limit. However I have a pastebin note with the script http://pastebin.com/H2ksXhfp

Answer (score 0):

Well first off your ' character doesn't look like it is escaped.

```
'and here is my consumer key, so i can't write'
```

Without seeing more code I can only speculate, but it looks to me like you have unescaped quotes and syntax issues. Take a look here for details on your error.

http://www.cs.arizona.edu/people/mccann/errors-python#Four

Comment: I don't know what to say, as I said I don't undestand much this, just i followed some tutorials and at the final step I hit by this error. The whole code when i try to put here it's say the -body limit is 30000-. Only I have a pastebin note where I've pasted the entire script http://pastebin.com/H2ksXhfp.